# Configure deluge-console plugins (Notifications)

Tags: linux, bittorrent, torrent

I have successfully setup deluge and tested downloading torrent on the server (everything works). I am more conformable on facing terminal and tried enabling the `plugins` from the deluge-console (specifically `Notifications`) though it says it's enable, I am not sure where to configure it to send email.

There is an available [link](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?t=49847) that gives a guide on how to do it, but none from a deluge-console standpoint.

Anyone had tried it before? Or any alternative solution for this?
By the way, I am running Debian 8 Jessie on my server.